# Warum wird »Richtung« auch großgeschrieben, wenn es als Präposition genutzt wird?

Tags: preposition, spelling, capitalization, denominalization

> der Bus **Richtung** Hannover
>
> Die Vögel ziehen **Richtung** Osten.
>
> Wir fahr’n auf Feuerrädern **Richtung** Zukunft durch die Nacht.
>
> Ich hoffe, dass **Richtung** Alpen mehr Schnee liegt.

In den obigen Beispielen verhält sich *Richtung* wie eine Präposition und intuitiv schriebe ich es klein. Andererseits listet weder irgendein Wörterbuch noch die Wörterliste der offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln das Wort *richtung* (kleingeschrieben). Letztere enthält sogar einen Eintrag:

> **Richtung** [Hannover, Osten …]

Ich vermute, dass dieser mir sagen möchte, dass ich *Richtung* in den obigen Fällen großschreibe.

Anderseits verhält sich *Richtung* in diesen Fällen wie eine Präposition; es ist zum Beispiel grammatikalisch analog zu Präpositionen wie *nach, gen* oder *aus.* In ähnlichen Fällen, wo ein Substantiv wie eine Präposition genutzt wird, wird dieses auch kleingeschrieben:

> Die VG Wort ist ein rechtsfähiger Verein **kraft** Verleihung.
>
> Er fürchtete sich **zeit** seines Lebens vor Gummibärchen.

Für eine Desubstantivierung (und damit Kleinschreibung) spricht meines Erachtens auch, dass ich *Richtung* hier nicht beugen oder mit einem Adjektiv versehen kann. Zwar kann ich es durch *in Richtung* ersetzen, aber ähnliches gilt auch für *zeit* und *kraft.*

Deshalb frage ich: Warum wird *Richtung* großgeschrieben, auch wenn es als Präposition genutzt wird? Oder liege ich mit meiner Klassifizierung als Präposition falsch (und falls ja, warum)? Wo ist der Unterschied zu anderen Präpositionen, die aus Desubstativierungen entstanden sind, wie *kraft* und *zeit?*

Comment: Ich wage zu bezweifeln, dass *Richtung* hier "als Präposition benutzt wird". Ich fasse dein Beispiel als eine verkürzte Form von "...in die Richtung von Hannover..." auf.

Comment: Siehe meinen vorletzten Absatz: Ich kann *zeit meines Lebens* auch durch *in der Zeit meines Lebens* ersetzen oder *Verein kraft Verleihung* durch *Verein aus der Kraft der Verleihung.*

Comment: *zeit* (mit Gen.) und *kraft* (mit Gen.) kann ich in vielen Listen von deutschen Präpositionen finden, *dank* (mit Gen.) übrigens auch - *Richtung* nicht. Das ist ein starker Hinweis darauf, dass es keine Präposition **ist** ;) Aber: Gute Frage! Ist es der fehlende Genitiv?

Comment: @tofro: Das wirft natürlich direkt die Frage auf, warum es keine Präposition ist (deren Beantwortung dann auch meine Frage beantworten würde).

Comment: Ich *tippe* auf den Genitiv - Alle Präpositionen, die aus Substantiven entstanden sind, tragen den Genitiv - ich kenne kein Gegenbeispiel. Aber der Genitiv funktioniert mit einer Zielangabe eben nicht - Die will den Akkusativ.

Comment: Noch ein ähnliches Beispiel: "Im Rahmen meiner Forschung..." ist lt. Wikipedia auch ein präpositionaler Gebrauch, schreibt man auch groß.

Comment: @tofro: Da ist aber noch eine Präposition *(im)* vor. Niemand sagt: »Das habe ich Rahmen meiner Forschung gefunden.«

Comment: Drei Dinge. 1.) Eine Präposition ist ›Richtung‹, glaube ich, nicht, so wie ›zeit‹ und ›kraft‹ keine sind. 2.) Richtung Osten ist ein wenig redundant; besser nach Osten (da Himmels_richtung_). 3.) Ich kann keinen Unterschied zwischen Desubstantivierungen wie ›kraft‹ oder ›zeit‹ und ›Richtung‹ erkennen. Beide werden in diesem Zusammenhang ausschließlich adverbial gebraucht. Konsistenter wäre es deshalb vermutlich, wenn die Zugvögel richtung Osten flögen. Das ist aber bloß eine Laienmeinung. Eine fundierte Antwort wirst du womöglich nur von einem Sprachwissenschaftler bekommen.

Comment: *Eine fundierte Antwort wirst du womöglich nur von einem Sprachwissenschaftler bekommen.* – Meiner Erfahrung nach schafft diese Seite es durchaus, fundierte Antworten hervorzubringen (dafür ist sie schließlich da). Und einige Nutzer sind sogar Sprachwissenschaftler.

Comment: @deponensvogel Widerspreche. *zeit* und *kraft* (so wie *trotz* und *dank* und weitere) sind sehr wohl Präpositionen - Da sind sich viele Wörterbücher einig. Was nicht heißt, das *Richtung* automatisch auch eine wäre.

Comment: Die Wörterbücher sind gut beraten, sich auf Orthographie zu konzentrieren. ›Trotz‹ und ›dank‹ sind Präpositionen, sobald man sie mit dem Dativ verwendet. ›Zeit‹ und ›kraft‹ sind eindeutig noch keine. Der Genitiv ist ein gutes Indiz dafür.

Comment: @deponensvogel Villeicht glaubst du ja dem IDS: http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gramwb.ansicht?v_app=p&v_kat=gramm&v_buchstabe=K&v_id=2545

Comment: @deponensvogel Das liest sich so, als könnten Präpositionen keinen Genitiv verlangen. Folglich wäre »trotz des Beispiels« keine Präposition,  »trotz dem Beispiel« aber schon. Welche Begründung hast du dafür parat? Vielleicht kannst du sie »anhand des Beispiels« hier ausformulieren?

Comment: @Jan Das ist eine Belles-Lettres-Lehrmeinung, die in vielen Videos sehr glaubhaft dargelegt wurde (demnach ist ›trotz des Beispiels‹ schlicht ungrammatisch). Ich gestehe, dass ich dem kleinen lilanen Podcast mehr vertraue als den blinden Abschreibern aus der Germanistik.

Comment: @deponensvogel »Anhand des Beispiels« hast du dabei völlig ignoriert. Ich wüsste gerne, welche Argumente Belles Lettres vorbringt, die eine Genitiv verlangende Präposition unmöglich machen. Im Finnischen, als Nebenpunkt, gibt übrigens eine ganze Reihe an Postpositionen (Finnisch ist in der Hinsicht eher *head-first),* die ausschließlich Genitiv erlauben; sind das dann auch keine Postpositionen, oder funktioniert das nur, weil Finnisch nicht indogermanisch ist?

Comment: @Jan Ich habe keine Ahnung vom Finnischen und kann das nicht beurteilen. Jedenfalls bezieht sich Belles Lettres rein aufs Indogermanische. ›Anhand‹ in ›anhand des Beispiels‹ ist doch eine schlichte Zusammenziehung, die man deshalb macht, weil man ›an‹ und ›Hand‹ sehr oft in dieser Kombination liest und es sich um eine erstarrte Phrase handelt. Trotzdem ist noch sehr klar zu sehen, dass der Genitiv nichts anderes als das Attribut zum Substantiv ›Hand‹ ist. ›Anhand von …‹ wäre ja andernfalls Präposition auf Präposition.

Comment: … Die Theorie von Belles Lettres zum Genitiv lautet kriminell verkürzt: Präpositionen sind räumliche Bezüge und können deshalb nur räumliche Kasus regieren, nicht aber den Genitiv, der selbst ein Bezug ist.

Comment: Ähnlich verwendet wird übrigens "Kurs" - "Die Titanic fuhr direkten Kurs SSW, als sie mit dem Eisberg kollidierte". Ist das dann auch eine Präposition?

Comment: @tofro: *"Die Titanic fuhr direkten Kurs SSW, als sie mit dem Eisberg kollidierte". Ist das dann auch eine Präposition?* – Das würde ich dann auf jeden Fall analog zu *Zug fahren* ansehen, insbesondere da hier *Kurs* offensichtlich durch ein Adjektiv erweiterbar ist (im Beispiel *direkten).*

Comment: Bemerkenswert, wie inkonsistent oft argumentiert wird. Ich hatte mir die Frage mit 'Richtung' auch schon oft gestellt. Es scheint, dass die Normen der Sprachwissenschaft wie die Normen des Justizwesens der Realität hinterherhinken. Ich denke, man sollte einfach eine anerkannte Definition von 'Präposition' hernehmen und dann prüfen, ob die dort genannten Kriterien erfüllt sind. Sind sie es, handelt es sich um eine Präposition. Ich zweifle bei 'Richtung' allenfalls daran, dass es einen Kasus regiert (Richtung alter/alten/altem Friedhof?), die anderen Merkmale einer Präposition werden erbracht.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Es ist eine Präposition

Erst einmal: Es ist keine Apposition, sondern tatsächliche eine Präposition. Grund? Erweiterungsprobe. Wenn *Richtung Hannover* eine Apposition wäre wie *Farbe Lila* oder *Kaiser Nero,* dann müsste sich der Kopf der Apposition erweitern lassen (ohne dass dabei die Nominalphrase ihren Status als Nominalphrase verliert).

Erweiterungsprobe:

- Farbe Lila → die Farbe Lila/die schöne Farbe Lila ist bezaubernd
- Kaiser Nero → unser Kaiser Nero/der umstrittene Kaiser Nero war ein grosser Imperator

Aber bei *Richtung Hannover:*

- Richtung Hannover ↛ *die Richtung Hannover/*die direkte Richtung Hannover ist eine schnelle Verbindung

Zwar lässt sich *Richtung Hannover* durchaus erweitern zu *in Richtung von Hannover,* aber das ist keine Nominalphrase mehr, sondern eine Präpositionalphrase, die typischerweise in der Rolle von Adverbialien verwendet werden.

*Nachschub 2019-04-02 mit besserem Beispiel: In einem Satz wie «der Bus Richtung Hannover war wieder einmal verspätet» lässt sich das Wort «Richtung» keinesfalls erweitern (und in der ursprünglichen Frage geht es ja um eine derartige Verwendung dieses Worts). Ein Satz wie «der Bus die ungefähre Richtung Hannover war wieder einmal verspätet» ist ungrammatisch.*

## Warum wird die Präposition nicht klein geschrieben?

Faule Antwort: Weil sie in der Liste von § 56 (4) der Rechtschreibregeln nicht aufgeführt ist, welcher lautet:

> Klein schreibt man Wörter, die formgleich als Substantive vorkommen, aber selbst keine substantivischen Merkmale aufweisen. Dies betrifft:
>
> […]
>
> die folgenden Präpositionen:
>
> *dank, kraft (kraft ihres Amtes), laut, statt, an ... statt (an Kindes statt, an seiner statt), trotz, wegen, von ... wegen (von Amts wegen), um ... willen, zeit (zeit seines Lebens)*

Längere Antwort: Vermutlich ist der Grund einfach morphologisch: Das Wort *Richtung* hat zwei Silben, und darüber hinaus ist die zweite Silbe eine der typischsten Substantivendungen. Die unter § 56 (4) aufgeführten Präpositionen sind hingegen entweder einsilbig *(dank, kraft, laut, trotz, zeit)* oder sie treten auch in nicht-substantivischem Kontext auf *(meinetwegen, meinetwillen).* Das Wort *Richtung* hat gewissermassen mehr substantivisches Gewicht – in einem derartigen Mass, dass wir es immer gross schreiben, selbst wenn es als Präposition verwendet wird.

Ähnlich ist es übrigens auch mit dem Wort *Anfang,* das ebenfalls präpositional verwendet werden kann.

Comment: Ich kann deine "Nicht-Apposition"-Begründung leider nicht nachvollziehen. *die direkte Richtung Hannover* ist doch perfekt?

Comment: "direkte Richtung" ist seltsam, eine Richtung kann nicht indirekt sein

Comment: Ich glaube eine bessere Antwort ist nicht möglich, da dazu Quellen aus dem RSR fehlen, ob die Frage dort überhaupt behandelt wurde und ob _richtung_ bewusst nicht in § 56 (4) aufgenommen wurde.

Comment: Ok, was ist mit "ungefähre Richtung Hannover"? Und eine Richtung kann sehr wohl indirekt sein, wenn ich z.B. indirekt in eine Richtung sehe, z.B. über einen Spiegel, oder wenn ich von hier aus (Ruhrgebiet) über Hamburg Richtung Hannover fahre.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Im Satz wäre das ein adverb des verbs: "... bewegt sich ungefähr Richtung Hannover".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Es geht hier um den Gebrauch von «Richtung Hannover» wie in «der Bus Richtung Hannover» oder «die Vögel ziehen Richtung Osten» (vgl. ursprüngliche Frage). Sätze wie «der Bus die ungefähre Richtung Hannover [war wieder einmal verspätet]» oder «die Vögel ziehen die indirekte Richtung Osten» sind ungrammatisch.

Comment: Sind sie wirklich ungrammatisch? Unüblich, ungewöhnlich, ja, aber ungrammatisch? Finde ich nicht.

Comment: FWIW, der "der Bus Richtung Hannover" ist m.E. kurz für "der Bus in Richtung Hannover". Da ist es dann deutlich, was die Präposition ist.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Nein, Präpositionen kann man nicht weglassen. Eine Phrase wie «die Flausen in meinem Kopf» lässt sich nicht kürzen zu «die Flausen meinem Kopf». Und da du das wieder bestreiten wirst: Meinen starken Verdacht, dass eine solche Konstruktion (oder ein Satz wie «der Bus die ungefähre Richtung Hannover war wieder einmal verspätet») ungrammatisch ist, kannst du sehr einfach widerlegen, indem du eine einzige Textstelle mit einem Gegenbeispiel findest.

Comment: @mach: anscheinend doch, in bestimmten Konstrukten. Beispiele sind "In Richtung Hannover", "Am Anfang des Jahres" oder "Am Ende des Tages". <g>

Answer (score 10):

Ich würde bei "Richtung Osten" ganz einfach annehmen, dass hier ein Substantiv zur näheren Bestimmung eines anderen Substantivs dient - so wie in

> die Farbe Lila
>
> der Planet Erde
>
> der Kaiser Nero
>
> der Ton Cis
>
> ein Glas Wein

da sowohl "Osten" als auch "Richtung" alleine keinen Sinn ergeben.

Damit ergibt sich für den Satz

> Ich fahre Richtung Osten

genau die selbe Satzstellung wie bei

> Ich fahre Zug.

also eine *adverbiale Bestimmung* durch ein Substantiv.

Um eine Präposition handelt sich es meiner Meinung nach nicht, sondern eher um eine Apposition.

Comment: Klingt gut, aber wie heißt das dann, Referenzen? Apposition scheint es nicht zu sein, oder?!

Comment: Mir ist etwas aufgefallen, das gegen diese Einstufung spricht: In »Ich fahre Zug« kann ich *Zug* durch ähnliche Substantive ersetzen, z. B. »Ich fahre ICE« oder »Ich fahre Güterzug«. Mit *Richtung* funktioniert das nicht: »Ich fahre Himmelsrichtung Osten« ist kein valides Deutsch.

Comment: Ich habe der Frage noch ein Beispiel hinzugefügt, wo *Richtung* zur Bestimmung des Satzes und nicht eines Verbs genutzt wird und daher die Parallele zu »Ich fahre Zug« fehlschlägt.

Comment: Dass es doch als bzw. wie eine Präposition verwendet wird, merkt man leicht an der **Ersetzungsprobe** mit _nach_ oder _gen_ – aber u.U. auch _Ziel_. Für die Herkunft gibt es hingegen keinen entsprechenden Ersatz zu _aus_ und (besonders im Bahndeutsch) _von_, obwohl ich mir fachsprachlich _Ursprung_, _Herkunft_ oder _Start_ durchaus präpositional gebraucht vorstellen kann.

Answer (score 3):

- > der Bus Richtung Hannover

  Der Bus **in die** Richtung Hannover
- > Die Vögel ziehen Richtung Osten.

  Die Vögel ziehen **in die** Richtung Osten
- > Wir fahr’n auf Feuerrädern Richtung Zukunft durch die Nacht.

  Wir fahr’n auf Feuerrädern **in die** Richtung Zukunft durch die Nacht.
- > Richtung [Hannover, Osten …]

  das soll dir sagen, dass **die** Richtung als Substantiv groß geschrieben wird. Auch in Verbindung mit den Wörtern in der Klammer.
  Also *Richtung Hannover* und *Richtung Osten.*

*Richtung* ist hier als Substantiv verwendet.

- > Die VG Wort ist ein rechtsfähiger Verein kraft Verleihung.

  Hier geht nicht:

  > * Die VG Wort ist ein rechtsfähiger Verein **die** kraft Verleihung.
- > Er fürchtete sich zeit meines Lebens vor Gummibärchen.

  Hier geht nicht:

  > * Er fürchtete sich **die** zeit meines Lebens vor Gummibärchen.

*Kraft* und *zeit* sind hier nicht als Substantiv gebraucht.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, wo Du den Unterschied zwischen *kraft* und *zeit* auf der einen Seite und *Richtung* auf der anderen Seite siehst: »Er fürchtete sich **in der Zeit** seines Lebens« ist zum Beispiel fast völlig analog zu »Die Vögel ziehen **in die Richtung** Osten«.

Comment: Dann ja ;)  Dann wäre Zeit ja auch ein Substantiv.
In deinem Beispiel ist es aber eine Präposition.
Richtung wird halt nicht zur Präposition.

http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/von-grossen-und-kleinen-zeiten

Comment: *In deinem Beispiel ist es aber eine Präposition. Richtung wird halt nicht zur Präposition.* – Ich kann Dir nicht folgen. Meinst Du, dass meine Beispielsätze grammatikalisch falsch wären?

Comment: das bezog sich auf zeit:  In deinem Beispiel ist es aber eine Präposition.

nein. Richtung ist halt nur keine Präposition.

Es gibt halt auch Regeln, die sind halt so. Da gibt es keine Erklärung.

Comment: *das bezog sich auf zeit: In deinem Beispiel ist es aber eine Präposition.* – Okay, aber das kann ich auch auf *Richtung* anwenden. Ich stimme Dir voll und ganz zu, dass *Richtung* in »Zug in die Richtung Osten« oder »Zug in Richtung Osten« ein Substantiv ist. Aber ich sehe keinen Grund, warum ich es in »Zug richtung Osten« ein Substantiv ist, ebensowenig wie ich behaupten würde, dass *zeit* in »zeit seines Lebens« ein Substantiv ist. Da kann man jetzt sagen: »ist halt so«, daraus erwächst aber keine konsistente Grammatik oder Rechtschreibung.

Comment: In jeder Sprache gibt es unregelmäßigkeiten. Und ich hoffe, dass ist jetzt nicht das erste Mal, dass dir das im Deutschen begegnet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51653/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-frankaus5419135).

Comment: Osten ist ja dem Wesen nach eine Richtung. Nicht so Hannover. Daher würde ich *Der Bus in die Richtung Hannovers* mit Genitiv-S schreiben.

Comment: Wenn man schon wilkürlich Worte einfügt, kann man das Spiel auch weiter treiben: "... wegen der Kraft der Verleihung".

Answer (score 2):

Präpositionen regieren üblicherweise einen Kasus: *mit* → Dativ, *für* → Akkusativ, *wegen* → Genitiv (gehoben/schriftsprachlich) / Dativ (umgangssprachlich/gesprochen-sprachlich), *in* → Akkusativ (Zielort) / Dativ (Ort des Sich-Befindens) usw. Nicht zu den Präpositionen zählen daher *als* und *wie* als Kopf einer Nominalphrase, die ihren Kasus vom Vergleichsnomen beziehen:

> **Er** war als engagiert**er** Mitarbeiter bekannt. / 
>   Man kannte **ihn** als engagiert**en** Mitarbeiter.

Welchen Kasus regiert die Präposition – so es denn eine ist – *Richtung*?

Das ist nicht leicht herauszufinden, da ein präpositionales *Richtung* sich sehr oft mit artikellosen Substantiven bzw. Eigennamen verbindet:

> Fahren Sie Richtung Innenstadt oder Richtung Chorweiler?

An der Formulierung mit Zielorten statt Richtungen sieht man bereits, dass *Richtung* sich in Verbindung mit Gattungsnamen nicht verhält wie eine gewohnte lokale Präposition:

> Fahren Sie zur Innenstadt oder nach Chorweiler?

Zurück zur Frage der Kasusrektion.

Welches der Folgenden würde man sagen?

- > Ich fahre Richtung alter Friedhof.
- > Ich fahre Richtung alten Friedhof.
- > Ich fahre Richtung altem Friedhof.

*Alter Friedhof* kann vielleicht wie *Alter Markt* oder *Hohe Straße* in Köln als nicht flektierbarer Eigenname aufgefasst werden. Bei *alten Friedhof* wäre wegen der Artikellosigkeit die starke Deklination und also ein Akkusativ anzusetzen. Die dritte Variante *Richtung altem Friedhof* könnte eine nachlässige Analogiebildung zu *zum alten Friedhof* sein, aber meines Erachtens scheidet diese Dativversion als inkorrekt aus.

Wenn *Richtung* der Status einer Präposition zuerkannt werden soll, verhält es sich jedenfalls nicht wie viele andere Zielort-Präpositionen, sondern ähnlich wie *gen* oder *via*. Es wird wohl vorrangig mit Eigennamen kombiniert (wobei z.B. bei Ländern mit Artikeln dieser weggelassen wird: *Richtung Schweiz / Richtung Türkei*), und es schluckt sozusagen auch bei Gattungsnamen regelmäßig den Artikel (*zum Bahnhof*, aber *Richtung Bahnhof*).

Was die Frage angeht, zu welcher grammatischen Kategorisierung man berechtigt ist, vielleicht noch die Bemerkung, dass es eine ganze Reihe von Phänomenen im Deutschen gibt, denen die Schulgrammatik nicht den Status zuerkennt, als der er von sehr vielen Sprachteilnehmern empfunden wird. In der Fahrschule haben wir gelernt, dass eine durchgezogene weiße Linie unter keinen Umständen überfahren werden darf. Im täglichen Verkehr stellt sich das als unpraktikabel heraus, wenn rechts z.B ein Möbelwagen steht. In der Grammatik gibt es solche Diskrepanzen u.a. bei *nicht brauchen* als Modalverb, bei *möchten* als nicht-existierende abgeschwächte Form von *wollen*, bei der Unterscheidung von Artikelwörtern und Begleitern, soweit es die Deklination nachfolgender Adjektive steuert, bei von Einwohnerbezeichnungen abgeleiteten Herkunftsadjektiven, bei der Deklination nicht deklinierbarer Farbadjektive usw. Wenn viele *Richtung* als Präposition empfinden, dann deswegen, weil es wie eine Präposition funktioniert. Eine Anerkennung solcher Tatbestände durch die Grammatik wird immer erst nachträglich erfolgen, so wie *während* anfangs immer einfaches Partizip Präsens war und heute längst als Konjunktion und Präposition anerkannt ist.

Mag sein, dass der Wortartstatus von *Richtung* in den hier besprochenen Verbindungen sich noch nicht stabilisiert hat.

Answer (score 2):

Möglicherweise wurde das fehlende *in* einfach nur verschluckt: »Wir fahr’n’n’Richtung Greifswald«. Das wäre dann eine Ellipse. Das einzige zulässige transformative Argument wäre eben eines mit Herleitung. Dabei muss aber zugestanden werden, dass nicht nur die Produktion der Phrase, sondern auch deren Wahrnehmung zählt.

Denn syntaktisch bewegt es sich dann wie eine Präposition. Morphologisch ist es aber nach wie vor unstreitbar ein Substantiv auf *-ung*.

Welches Argument dabei den Vorzug erhält, ist subjektiv, finde ich. Denn ich würde es vermutlich klein schreiben, ohne Kenntnis der Vorschriften, am ehesten aber gar nicht, sondern immer »in Richtung«, »in die Richtung von«, da die Dissonanz, die zur hiesigen Frage führt, die Konstruktion geradezu ungrammatikalisch erscheinen lässt.

Vergleich auch: »Ich studiere Physik«. Physik ist gewissermaßen eine Richtungsangabe, immerhin findet sich auch »Ich studiere Physik, Fachrichtung Metaphysik«. So könnte man sich gleichfalls »Der Zug Hannover–Eschenbach« vorstellen. Darin tritt keine strikte Präposition auf. Präpositionen werden allgemeinhin als eine abgeschlossene Klasse (en. *closed class*) wahrgenommen, will ich meinen.

Wikipedia [schreibt)[https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortart]
:

> Die Wortart ist zu unterscheiden von der syntaktischen Funktion (Satzfunktion) eines Wortes ...

Insofern stellt sich die Frage nach entweder-oder überhaupt nicht.

Denn die »Fachrichtung XY« ist sicherlich eine adverbiale Phrase, sowie »Bett« in »Bettlägerich« (En. »bed ridden«, beachte die Trennung).

Es dürfte entscheidend sein, dass die Frage etwas ambivalent ist, denn so werden Neuschöpfungen ermöglicht. Ist *ich* nicht auch ein Substantiv? Wieso wird »das Ich« als solches aufgefasst, aber »(Das) Ich sagte ...« regulär verneint? Dafür gibt es keine gute Antwort.

Um das Ausschweifen der Großschreibung zu vermeiden, wird in der Regel Kleinschreibung Präferenz sein. Sonst wird Irgendwann jedes Wort Großschreibung, der Sinn von Großschreiben geht Weg, und die Sprache zum Analytischen.

Comment: Ähnliche Zweifel kann man auch an der Englischen Großschreibung von proper-nouns äußern, denn die Abgrenzung zu common-nouns ist nicht hinreichend deutlich.

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube du siehst den Fokus nicht ganz richtig.
Eigentlich liegt der Fokus auf *Richtung*, dass sich also etwas bewegt, und zwar nicht wahllos, sondern eben gezielt.
Die Angaben hinter *Richtung* spezifizieren wohin (in welche Richtung) es geht. Beim Bus könnte das besonders deutlich werden: Ein Bus hat das Ziel normalerweise vorne in einer Anzeige. Das könnte z.B. auch „Am Markt“ sein. Dann würde es wie folgt lauten:

> der Bus (in die) Richtung am Markt

bzw. ich würde dann noch Anführungszechen dazu setzen:

> der Bus (in die) Richtung „Am Markt“

Comment: Ich sehe nicht, wie das meine Frage beantwortet.

Comment: Ich wollte damit ausdrücken, dass "Richtung" nicht Präposition von "Hannover" ist, sondern das Substantiv. ich bin nur nicht so fit mit den Fachbegriffen wie tofro, der/die das besser kann.

Answer (score -1):

Richtung ist ein Nomen, keine Präposition. Warum? such einfach im Duden, 
[image]

Aber Zeit ist ja ein Nomen und eine Präposition. Warum? so steht im Duden,

[image]

In welche Richtung fährst du?
In Richtug Osten. 
oder
(in) Richtung Osten.

aber nicht

Welche Richtung fährst du?

Comment: Meine Frage war nicht, was im Duden steht, sondern gewissermaßen warum der Duden das so beurteilt. Es ist ja nicht so, dass der Duden die Sprache bestimmt, sondern umgekehrt (siehe auch [Präskriptivismus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription)). Meine Frage und einige der Antworten liefern auch Argumente dafür, dass es in der Tat eine Präposition ist, die halt nur großgeschrieben wird.